# Titan cassandra does not use defined indexes for custom gremlin steps

Tags: indexing, cassandra, gremlin, titan

We have defined 5 indexes using titan cassandra in the follow block of code

```
 def mgmt = g.managementSystem;
 try {
     if (!mgmt.containsGraphIndex("byId")) {
         def key = mgmt.makePropertyKey('__id').dataType(String.class).make()
         mgmt.buildIndex("byId",Vertex.class).addKey(key).buildCompositeIndex()
     }
     if (!mgmt.containsGraphIndex("byType")) {
          def key = mgmt.makePropertyKey('__type').dataType(String.class).make()
         mgmt.buildIndex("byType",Vertex.class).addKey(key).buildCompositeIndex()
     }
     if (!mgmt.containsGraphIndex("lastName")) {
         def key = mgmt.makePropertyKey('lastName').dataType(String.class).make()
         mgmt.buildIndex('lastName',Vertex.class).addKey(key).buildMixedIndex(INDEX_NAME)
     }
     if (!mgmt.containsGraphIndex("firstName")) {
         def key = mgmt.makePropertyKey('firstName').dataType(String.class).make()
         mgmt.buildIndex('firstName',Vertex.class).addKey(key).buildMixedIndex(INDEX_NAME)
     }
     if (!mgmt.containsGraphIndex("vin")) {
         def key = mgmt.makePropertyKey('vin').dataType(String.class).make()
         mgmt.buildIndex('vin',Vertex.class).addKey(key).buildMixedIndex(INDEX_NAME)
     }
     mgmt.commit()
 } catch (Exception e) {
     System.err.println("An error occurred initializing indices")
     e.printStackTrace()
 }
```

we then execute the following query

```
g.V.has('__id','49fb8bae5f994cf5825b849a5dd9b49a')
```

This produces a warning informing us that :

"Query requires iterating over all vertices [{}]. For better performance, use indexes"

I'm confused because according to the documentation these indexes are set up correctly, but for some reason titan is not using them.

The indexes are created before any data is in the graph, so reindexing is not neccessary. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update-** 
I've managed to break this down into a very simple test. In our code we have developed a custom gremlin step to use for the stated query

```
Gremlin.defineStep('hasId', [Vertex,Pipe], { String id ->
    _().has('__id', id)
})
```

then from our code we call

```
g.V.hasId(id)
```

It appears that when we use the custom gremlin step the query does not use the index, but when using the vanilla gremlin call the index is used.

It looks like a similar oddity was noted in this post
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aureliusgraphs/6DqMG13_4EQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to check for existence of the property key which would mean you adjust your checks to:

```
if (!mgmt.containsRelationType("__id")) {
```

I tried out your code in the Titan Gremlin Console and I'm not seeing an issue:

```
gremlin> g  = TitanFactory.open("conf/titan-cassandra.properties")
==>titangraph[cassandrathrift:[127.0.0.1]]
gremlin> mgmt = g.managementSystem
==>com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem@2227a6c1
gremlin> key = mgmt.makePropertyKey('__id').dataType(String.class).make()
==>__id
gremlin> mgmt.buildIndex("byId",Vertex.class).addKey(key).buildCompositeIndex()
==>com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.management.TitanGraphIndexWrapper@6d4c273c
gremlin> mgmt.commit()
==>null
gremlin> mgmt = g.managementSystem
==>com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem@79d743e6
gremlin> mgmt.containsGraphIndex("byId")
==>true
gremlin> mgmt.rollback()
==>null
gremlin> v = g.addVertex()
==>v[256]
gremlin> v.setProperty("__id","123")
==>null
gremlin> g.commit()
==>null
gremlin> g.V
12:56:45 WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx  - Query requires iterating over all vertices [()]. For better performance, use indexes
==>v[256]
gremlin> g.V("__id","123")
==>v[256]
gremlin> g.V.has("__id","123")
==>v[256]
```

Note I'm not getting any ugly message about "...use indexes".  Perhaps you can try my example here and see if that behaves as expected before going back to your code.

UPDATE: In answer to the updated question above with respect to the custom step.  As the post you found noted, Titan's query optimizer doesn't seem to be able to sort this one out.  I think it's easy to see why in this example:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> Gremlin.defineStep('hasName', [Vertex,Pipe], { n -> _().has('name',n) })
==>null
gremlin> g.V.hasName('marko')
==>v[1]
gremlin> g.V.hasName('marko').toString()
==>[GremlinStartPipe, GraphQueryPipe(vertex), [GremlinStartPipe, PropertyFilterPipe(name,EQUAL,marko)]]
```

The "compiled" Gremlin looks like that last line above.  Note that custom step compiles to an "inner" pipe with a new `GremlinStartPipe`.  Compare that to the same without the custom step:

```
gremlin> g.V.has('name','marko').toString()
==>[GremlinStartPipe, GraphQueryPipe(has,vertex), IdentityPipe]
```

Titan can optimize the "GraphQueryPipe" with embedded `has`, but it seems that isn't the case with the custom step's signature.  I think the workaround (at least for this particular scenario is write a function that returns the pipe.

```
gremlin> def hasName(g,n){g.V.has('name',n)}  
==>true
gremlin> hasName(g,'marko')
==>v[1]
gremlin> hasName(g,'marko').toString()
==>[GremlinStartPipe, GraphQueryPipe(has,vertex), IdentityPipe]
```

Passing 'g' around kinda stinks.  Perhaps write your DSL so that 'g' gets wrapped in an class that then lets you do:

```
with(g).hasName('marko')
```

A final thought would be to use Groovy meta-programming facilities:

```
gremlin> Graph.metaClass.hasName = { n -> delegate.V.has('name',n) }
==>groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1@600b9d27
gremlin> g.hasName("marko").toString()                              
==>[GremlinStartPipe, GraphQueryPipe(has,vertex), IdentityPipe]
gremlin> g.hasName("marko")                                         
==>v[1]
```

Comment: Any explanation to go along with that? The docs say [`containsGraphIndex`](http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/javadoc/0.5.0-M1/com/thinkaurelius/titan/core/schema/TitanManagement.html) checks "whether the graph has a graph index defined with the given name," and [`containsRelationType`](http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/javadoc/0.5.0/com/thinkaurelius/titan/core/TitanTransaction.html) checks whether a type with the specified name exists. This is not very enlightening.

Comment: Change that condition causes the indexes to be created every time the graph is initialized. This produces an exception the second time through.

 "Adding this property for key [system%&%SchemaName] and value [rt%__id] violates a uniqueness constraint [com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.types.system.BaseKey$1@d35feb2]"

Comment: Also we can debug through this block of code and see that the index is being built. We just don't know why it's not being used when execute our query.

Comment: hmmm - sorry - i totally misread your questions.  i thought you were checking for existence of the property key, but you are checking for existence of the index itself, so i guess that much is right.  edit above...maybe i got it right this time.

Comment: Do you need to define it as unique? It's pretty much copied directly from [here](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/current/indexes.html).

Comment: I guess you don't need to enforce a unique constraint - i read that from `GraphOfTheGodsFactory` source code (my goto example source for how Titan indexing works).  Anyway, I just tried your code for myself and I didn't have the problem - updated my answer again, as I keep giving you a less than great advice....does the code I present in the console above work for you?

Comment: I ran the code through the gremlin console however I got not warnings even when running g.V. Please see the updated question

Comment: OK, I forgot to mention that I'm on a windows system. It would appear that the gremlin console .bat file does not configure logging, so that is why I was not getting any logging output. Not to take focus away from the real issue which still persists in the actual application.

Comment: I updated my original question with some more detail. Just ignore the previous question about the gremlin console.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. It is a very good explanation for the issue. The workaround solutions are also great. Are there any plans to improve on the query optimizer to read into gremlin statements with "inner" pipes in the future? The current optimizer is limiting us on some of the abstractions we can use with gremlin steps.

Comment: TP3 do wonders to a vendor's capability to optimize a traversal: http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/#traversalstrategy Titan 0.9 (next release) will take advantage of that for sure.  Offhand, I would think it would be possible to pick apart inner traversals, though i'm not sure.  I'll make sure it gets discussed internally.